# Modify list of objects using Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below array of objects with `vertical` as string and `projects` as array of objects inside it. `projects` can be empty too. Each `projects` entry if not empty, will have `name` and `releaseType` as properties.

```
[
  {
    "vertical": "Alpha",
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "releaseType": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "vertical": "Beta",
    "projects": []
  },
  {
    "vertical": "Gamma",
    "projects": [
      {
        "name": "Lincoln",
        "releaseType": "Google Pay"
      },
      {
        "name": "Madison",
        "releaseType": "PayPal"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get the list of projects in below format. Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. This isn't regular filter method, but it requires a bit of manipulation using map. I tried few things, but I was not able to achieve expected result.

```
[
  {
    "vertical": "Alpha",
    "feature": "Test",
     "releaseType": ""
  },
  {
    "vertical": "Gamma",
    "feature": "Lincoln",
     "releaseType": "Google Pay"
   },
   {
     "vertical": "Gamma",
     "feature": "Madison",
     "releaseType": "PayPal"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), should solve this pretty well:

```js
const input = [{vertical:"Alpha",projects:[{name:"Test",releaseType:""}]},{vertical:"Beta",projects:[]},{vertical:"Gamma",projects:[{name:"Lincoln",releaseType:"Google Pay"},{name:"Madison",releaseType:"PayPal"}]}];

const res = input.flatMap(e => 
  e.projects.flatMap(x => [{vertical: e.vertical, ...x}])
)

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` for resolve it

```
arr.reduce((pre, cur) => {
  if (cur.projects.length) {
    pre.push(...cur.projects.map(p => ({
      vertical: cur.vertical,
      feature: p.name,
      releaseType: p.releaseType,
    })))
  }

  return pre;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` for this

```
let formattedProjects = arr.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
    if (c.projects.length) {
        p = p.concat(c.projects.map(project => {
            return {
                vertical: c.vertical,
                feature: project.name,
                releaseType: project.releaseType
            }
        }));
    }

    return p;
}, []);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6zk8jhat/

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [
  {
    vertical: "Alpha",
    projects: [
      {
        name: "Test",
        releaseType: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    vertical: "Beta",
    projects: [],
  },
  {
    vertical: "Gamma",
    projects: [
      {
        name: "Lincoln",
        releaseType: "Google Pay",
      },
      {
        name: "Madison",
        releaseType: "PayPal",
      },
    ],
  },
];

arr = arr
  .map((obj) => {
    return obj.projects.map((proj) => {
      return {
        vertical: obj.vertical,
        ...proj,
      };
    });
  })
  .flat();
```